# Найти цифру в списке и изменить если нет нужного значения

Tags: python, list, tuple

У меня есть такой кортеж. Хочу создать функцию, пройтись по значениям, если хоть в одном из них присутствует цифра 1, то пусть вернет весь список, а если нет - пусть вместо всего списка вернет 0.

```
find_one([1, 1],[3,4,5],[4,1])->[[1, 1], 0, [4, 1]]
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
test = ([1, 1],[3,4,5],[4,1])

def find_one(s):
    if 1 in s:
        return s
    return 0


def find_one_total(src):
    for x in src:
        result = find_one(x)
        print(result)    

find_one_total(test)
```